# Using Mathematica to make a graphics array of circles

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation

I need to make .svg file that contains an array of black circles that all have radii of 5 units ad are evenly spaced apart from each other 32 units.

The difficulty in creating this design is the sheer number of circles necessary. I will need a 3175 by 3175 array. At first I tried doing this manually in Adobe Illustrator, but then it occurred to me that I could write a code to do it for me in Mathematica.

```
n = 50;
mat = Flatten[Table[{32 i, 32 j}, {i, 0, n - 1, 1}, {j, 0, n - 1, 1}], 1];
g = Disk[#, 5] & /@ mat;
Export["circle_array.svg", Graphics[g], "SVG"];
```

Above is the code I wrote, and it for a small number of rows/columns, it works just fine. After it's created, I open it up in Adobe Illustrator, and it looks just fine.

However, when I try to increase the number of rows much greater than 100 X 100, after it's exported and I open it up in Adobe Illustrator. I notice that not all the circles are evenly spaced away from each other, and I don't understand why.

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do they look evenly spaced prior to exporting? i.e. does `Graphics[g]` look OK in Mathematica?

Comment: It looks correct for me in `PDF`: picture [here](http://i.imgur.com/kM46Ke5.png).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the odd spacing? Perhaps a screenshot would help. Could this be a rendering issue with AI? Oh,  and do you want circles or disks?

Answer (score 6):

If you use Adobe Illustrator, the most natural format is not SVG, but PDF. This file loads in a fraction of the time which SVG needs and the issue is fixed.

```
n = 200;
mat = Flatten[Table[{32 i, 32 j}, {i, 0, n - 1, 1}, {j, 0, n - 1, 1}], 1];
g = Disk[#, 5] & /@ mat;
Export["circle_array.pdf", Graphics[g]];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the responses, everyone, but I guess my problems occurred when I continued to increased the dimensions. I ultimately need a 3175X3175 array but the computation time is a big hindrance. I need to submit this file to be printed, and they actually only accept a DXF format. I saw you can create this kind of file with Mathematica, but when I tried to import into Illustrator to view, that was also another problem, as it appeared to be corrupted. My work-around was to create a SVG, import into Illustrator, and then have Illustrator convert to DXF and that's when I noticed the odd spacing.

Comment: `DXF` export does a *terrible* job with `Disk`, as it tries to approximate the disk with a number of polygons. This bloats the dxf file and takes about forever. `Circle` works better, but for your huge number of circles dxf will be a really bad choice.

Comment: @SebastianFreeman OK, it would have been better to state from the beginning what your exact task is. Would it be possible that you join the [chat] so we can discuss a possible idea I have? (I know you currently don't have enough rep to do so, I hope this changes shortly).